# Display image on TChart (Borland Delphi 7)

Tags: image, delphi, delphi-7, pascal, teechart

I have a `TChart` in my Borland Delphi 7 project. What I want to do is to use an image instead of point while plotting on chart. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand what do you exactly want to achieve.

1. See the TImagePoint series. Find an example at "All features\Welcome !\Chart styles\Other\Image Point"
2. See the `BackWall.Brush.Image` property. Find an example at "All features\Welcome !\Miscellaneous\Walls\Back Wall\Brush image". Note you may have to set the back wall gradient invisible to make the image appear.

These examples are included in the [TeeChart compiled demo](https://www.steema.com/download/vcl)